# HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled always true

Tags: configuration, appharbor

Why my site is running debug mode?

HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled is always true!

Bundles not working!

Although #if DEBUG is false so DEBUG is not defined!

Precompilation is enabled on my appharbor app.

In my Web.Release.config I remove debug:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
</system.web>
```

Online Transformation Tester give me this result tested with my Web.config and Web.Release.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  Para obtener más información sobre cómo configurar la aplicación de ASP.NET, visite
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=9831a429-a608-4055-8bb9-a2bb016f79a3.sqlserver.sequelizer.com;Initial Catalog=db9831a429a60840558bb9a2bb016f79a3;user id=wgomqcwgmezvqifh;password=JqgJKAdNmPvR6ZSwsVJYZtP7VYE2pZaTmn6Mntozm4r8TjtMAEFZRwzqHhVT4kxu;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="StorageConnectionString" connectionString="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="TwitterKey" value="{TwitterKey}" />
    <add key="TwitterSecret" value="{TwitterSecret}" />
    <add key="FacebookKey" value="{FacebookKey}" />
    <add key="FacebookSecret" value="{FacebookSecret}" />
    <add key="MicrosoftKey" value="{MicrosoftKey}" />
    <add key="MicrosoftSecret" value="{MicrosoftSecret}" />
    <add key="AnalyticsCode" value="{AnalyticsCode}" />
    <add key="AnalyticsDomain" value="{AnalyticsDomain}" />
    <add key="CrawlerServiceApiId" value="{CrawlerServiceApiId}" />
    <add key="CrawlerServiceApplication" value="{CrawlerServiceApplication}" />
    <add key="CrawlerServiceEndPoint" value="{CrawlerServiceEndPoint}" />
    <add key="EmailServer" value="{EmailServer}" />
    <add key="EmailUser" value="{EmailUser}" />
    <add key="EmailPassword" value="{EmailPassword}" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.OData" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.0.0" newVersion="5.6.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.0" newVersion="2.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.0" newVersion="2.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.0" newVersion="2.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.0" newVersion="2.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.OData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.0.0" newVersion="5.6.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm have the same issue.
Temporarily, I'm using this workaround found in http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/managing-environments.

```
<add key="Environment" value="Debug"/>
```

Appharbor will replace the value="Debug" to the environment that was set in AppHarbor https://appharbor.com/applications/{appname}/edit

.

Instead of checking for HttpContext.IsDebugingEnabled, I'll check for

```
var isInDebugMode = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Environment"].Equals("Debug", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Answer (score 5):

When debugging from Visual Studio, your web.config transforms are NOT applied.  This means your default Web.config likely has the line `<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1"/>` , emphasizing the `debug="true"`.

Removing the `debug="true"` attribute from the compilation element in your base Web.config file will make `HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled` equal to false.

Some other options: If you are trying to see if the request is from your local machine, you can check for `Request.IsLocal` instead of `HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled`,  or to check for an active debugger `Debugger.IsAttached`

Comment: Interestingly enough, I am having the problem where Debugger.IsAttached is always returning true even on deployed production systems.